# Attribute Error while using super() in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

This is a piece of Python code to learn inheritance.

```
class Animal():
    __name= None
    __sound = None

    def __init__(self, name , sound):
        self.__name= name
        self.__sound = sound 
    def ToString(self):
        print ("The {} has the sound  {}".format(self.__name ,
                                                self.__sound))


cat = Animal('Tiger' , 'roars')
cat.ToString()


class Panther(Animal):
    __owner = None

    def __init__(self , name ,sound ,owner):
        self.__owner = owner
        super(Panther ,self).__init__(name, sound)
    def ToString(self):
        print(self.__owner)
        print(self.__name) 

leopard = Panther('Leopard' , 'roars' , 'Senegal')
leopard.ToString()
```

But when I try to run it in Pycharm, I get the following error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5
>   /Users/venkat/PycharmProjects/PythonOneVideo/main.py The Tiger has the
>   sound  roars Senegal Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/venkat/PycharmProjects/PythonOneVideo/main.py", line 41, in
>   
>       leopard.ToString()   File "/Users/venkat/PycharmProjects/PythonOneVideo/main.py", line 35, in
>   ToString
>       print(self.__name) AttributeError: 'Panther' object has no attribute '_Panther__name'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

What's wrong with calling the super class constructor?
Why this error has happened and how to solve this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

several issues:

- python 3 syntax for `super`: `super().__init__(name, sound)`
- [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables): instance variables starting with `__` (two underscores) will get `_ClassName` prepended to them. child classes will not be able to access them the usual way.
- `ToString`: why not `__str__` (and do not print inside `__str__`; just return a `str`)?
- and what are the class variables (`_name` etc) for? why not just have them as instance variables (`self._name`)?

this works bus is incomplete...

```
class Animal():
    # _name= None
    # _sound = None

    def __init__(self, name , sound):
        self._name= name
        self._sound = sound

#    def ToString(self):
#        print ("The {} has the sound  {}".format(self._name ,
#                                                self._sound))

    def __str__(self):
        fmt = 'The {self._name} has the sound {self._sound}'
        return fmt.format(self=self)

cat = Animal('Tiger' , 'roars')
print(cat)

class Panther(Animal):
    # _owner = None

    def __init__(self , name ,sound ,owner):
        self.__owner = owner
        super().__init__(name, sound)

#    def ToString(self):
#        # print(self._owner)
#        print(self._name)

leopard = Panther('Leopard' , 'roars' , 'Senegal')
print(leopard)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the two leading underscore from your attributes:

```
class Animal():
    name= None
    sound = None

    def __init__(self, name , sound):
        self.name= name
        self.sound = sound 
    def ToString(self):
        print ("The {} has the sound  {}".format(self.name ,
                                                self.sound))


cat = Animal('Tiger' , 'roars')
cat.ToString()


class Panther(Animal):
    owner = None

    def __init__(self , name ,sound ,owner):
        self.owner = owner
        super(Panther ,self).__init__(name, sound)
    def ToString(self):
        print(self.owner)
        print(self.name) 

leopard = Panther('Leopard' , 'roars' , 'Senegal')
leopard.ToString()
```

Output:

```
The Tiger has the sound  roars
Senegal
Leopard
```

The two leading underscores make your attributes "private".
This is done my [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables), i.e. adding `_ClassName` in front of all attributes with two leading underscores. This prevents the inheritance you do from working.

Comment: Thanks Mike.It helped

Comment: This is Python's way to create something that can be use similarly to private attributes in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Your error stems from the name mangling Python performs when you prepend a variable name with `__`.  If you simply use names without the double trailing underscores, this works fine:

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self, name , sound):
        self._name= name
        self._sound = sound 
    def ToString(self):
        print ("The {} has the sound  {}".format(self._name ,
                                                self._sound))


cat = Animal('Tiger' , 'roars')
cat.ToString()


class Panther(Animal):

    def __init__(self , name ,sound ,owner):
        self._owner = owner
        super(Panther ,self).__init__(name, sound)
    def ToString(self):
        print(self._owner)
        print(self._name)
```

and prints out:

```
>>> leopard = Panther('Leopard' , 'roars' , 'Senegal')
>>> leopard.ToString()
The Tiger has the sound  roars
Senegal
Leopard
```